# examples of Kähler manifolds with trivial Hodge numbers and first Chern classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Yesterday I asked the following question to which abx has given a positive answer.

[examples of Kähler manifolds with trivial odd Betti numbers and first Chern classes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168029/examples-of-kahler-manifolds-with-trivial-odd-betti-numbers-and-first-chern-clas)

But I suddenly realized that those Fano manifolds I mentioned in the quesion above (flag manifolds $G/P$ and Fano contact manifolds) not only have trivial odd Betti numbers but have stronger properties: their Hodge numbers satisfy $h^{p,q}=0$ whenever $p\neq q$.

But the example abx mentioned (some smooth complete intersections) and the K3 surfaces seem not to support the above property.

So I would like to modify my original question by asking the following:
does there exist a compact Kähler manifold whose first Chern class is trivial such that
its Hodge numbers satisfy $h^{p,q}=0$ whenever $p\neq q$?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by vanishing of the first Chern class. On one hand, Enriques surfaces have $c_1 = 0$ in cohomology with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients and its Hodge diamond is diagonal. On the other hand, if  the canonical class of $X$ is trivial then $h^{n,0}(X) \ne 0$.

Comment: @Sasha What I mean is $c_1=0$ in $H^{2}(M;\mathbb{R})$. I want to know if, for any $n$, there exists an $n$-dimensional  example.

Comment: @Kevin: In that case Sasha's examples are valid -- you are killing the torsion in cohomology when you use $\mathbb{R}$-coefficients.  So there are Enriques surfaces, and many more examples in dimensions $>2$.

Answer (score 3):

If the Chern class vanishes over integers, it's Calabi-Yau manifold,
and it has a holomorphic (n,0)-form by Bogomolov's theorem (see there:
[Two definitions of Calabi-Yau manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15003/two-definitions-of-calabi-yau-manifolds/)).
If you relax your condition by asking $c_1$ to vanish over reals, then there are
many examples, such as an [Enriques surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriques_surface); its only non-zero Hodge numbers are
$h^{1,1}=10$, $h^{0,0}=1$, $h^{2,2}=1$.

The quotients of Calabi-Yau manifolds often satisfy $h^{p,q}=0$ for all $p\neq q$.
However, there is an interesting question (still unresolved, as far as I know): 
does  there exist a quotient of a compact torus which is Kahler and has this property?